# how to find only exact cases of the world "is" within another string, not including "is" that is part of word "this"

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn regular expression. I'm trying to find the exact world "is" within another string. Below is the code I have came up with.

```
int count = 0;
String text
        = "This is the text which is to be searched "
        + "for occurrences of the word 'is'.";

String patternString = "is";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(text);
while (m1.find()) {
    count++;
    System.out.printf("found %s %d: from index %d to index %d%n", 
            patternString, count, m1.start(), m1.end() );
}
```

However, not only did it found all "is", it also found "is" that is part of "this", which is not what I want. How could I find only exact cases of "is"?

Comment: depending on what kind of strings you are working with, the regex can get quite complicated. however, at the simplest, you can just use " is ". Notice the space around `is`.

Comment: @khuderm I dont see any space around "is", could you please elaborate on that a little bit? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this : `String patternString = "\\bis\\b";`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using negative lookarounds:

```
String patternString = "(?<!\\w)is(?!\\w)";
```

The regex

```
(?<!\w)is(?!\w)
```

matches the word `is` only if it's neither preceded nor followed by a word character (`\w`).

Output:

```
found (?<!\w)is(?!\w) 1: from index 5 to index 7
found (?<!\w)is(?!\w) 2: from index 23 to index 25
found (?<!\w)is(?!\w) 3: from index 70 to index 72
```